# qt creator: after RUN, start additional application

Tags: qt, debugging

I wrote apllication for embedded device and I use Qt creator. This is app is some server that open port and wait connections. I want start locally another apllication (for examle the "nc 1.5.1.105 10000") after deploy and start my application on remote device.
How to start another app locally, after deploy my app?

Comment: In the run section you can only specify one command. So just use a shell script that you run from Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding Deploy step -> Custom process step:

Command=xterm,

Arguments=-display ":0" -si -sk +bc -mesg -rightbar -sl 1000 -hold -e 'E=1; while [ $E -ne 0 ]; do nc 1.5.1.105 10000;let E=$?; done' &

Answer (score 1):

You can add some arguments in
[project->run section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8x8ut.png).
Just add "&" and command you want to execute after launching your app.
If you run gui app you can add something like `& xterm -hold -e nc...`

Comment: this worked on local mashine, but my application run on remote device. If I add Deploy step -> Custop process step: xterm -display ":0" -w 2 -hold -si -sk -e "nc 192.168.0.2 10000" &  The nc can not get in time connect to port and xterm show  blank screen. There need run nc after run my app on remote device.